# Using expo to alert user when he disabled GPS location sharing while using app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gps, location, expo

I'm building an expo google maps based app. I'm monitoring the user's location with `watchPositionAsync()` . I want to alert the user that he needs to enable location sharing if he disables it while using the app. Just like in google maps navigation.

So if I'm following a tour and if I disable location sharing from the mobile dropdown for example, I want to prompt an alert to enable it, because without the user's current location the navigation should not work.

The problem with this code is :

When I first time come to this component and I accept location sharing, then later if I disable location sharing while using the app, I don't get an alert. I need to use `setLocationEnabled(true);` somewhere but I don't know where

When I first come to this component and decline location sharing the first time, then if I enable location sharing again it won't get detected.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [watchId, setWatchId] = useState(null);
  const [locationEnabled, setLocationEnabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync();
      setLocationEnabled(true);
      console.log("location enabled");
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Location.watchPositionAsync(
      {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
        distanceInterval: 1,
        timeInterval: 10000,
      },
      (pos) => {
        setLocation(pos.coords);
      }
    )
      .then((locationWatcher) => {
        //set locationwatcher for removing
        setWatchId(locationWatcher);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLocationEnabled(false);
        console.log("watchpositon error: ", err.message);
      });

    return () => {
      watchId && watchId.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!locationEnabled) Alert.alert("You need to enable location sharing");
  }, [locationEnabled]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{JSON.stringify(location)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I ended up using `setInterval()` hook.
Here is an example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      (async () => {
          const res = await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync();
          if(!res) Alert.alert("No location")
        }
      })();
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Comment: is this not affect app, especially in terms of performance and battery usage?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to detect that the user comes back to your app (brings it back from background) and re-check permission when that happens. To do so, use `AppState` from `react-native`:

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

useEffect(() => {
  // handler for app state changes
  const handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState: AppStateStatus) => {
    setAppState(nextAppState);
  };

  // register the handler to listen for app state changes
  AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

  // unsubscribe
  return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // checks that app state changed to 'active' - user comes back from background or inactive state
  // note -- this will also trigger the first time you enter the screen
  if (appState === 'active') {
    // check location permission
    const locationPermission = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (locationPermission.status !== 'granted') {
      // TODO: alert user about missing location permission
    }
  }
}, [appState]);
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you. But expo offers background location tracking, should I check that out too? I'm guessing from your answer I can't do this with the foreground location tracking

Comment: The way I understand background location updates is the background task is only triggered when a location update is received - it won't be triggered when permission status or location services availability changes. From your use case, I think checking for permission changes when user comes back to the app is the way to go (note: I updated the snipped a bit as I think it had an edge case where the alert wouldn't show).

Comment: I understand, I will try out your solution shortly.

Comment: I tried your solution. This does not work when I turn off location sharing from the top notifications/settings drop down menu.

Comment: That is true, for tracking these events on Android, two other events are used - `focus` and `blur`. However, I did a quick check on expo.snack and found them not working testing on Android 11

Comment: So is there really no answer to my problem? :( On reddit somebody recommended me to use setIntervall hooks, to check every x second if the location is disabled. I think that is kinda bad solution